# How do you create vectors with specific intervals in R?

Tags: r, vector, intervals

I have a question about creating vectors. If I do `a <- 1:10`, "a" has the values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.

My question is how do you create a vector with specific intervals between its elements. For example, I would like to create a vector that has the values from 1 to 100 but only count in intervals of 5 so that I get a vector that has the values 5,10,15,20,...,95,100

I think that in Matlab we can do `1:5:100`, how do we do this using R?

I could try doing `5*(1:20)` but is there a shorter way? (since in this case I would need to know the whole length (100) and then divide by the size of the interval (5) to get the 20)

Comment: I know it is sometimes hard to come up with good search terms, but if I google "r sequence", the second hit is the help page of `seq`. The function is probably also part of most basic introductions to R.

Comment: Yea I tried several things and couldn't find it.. didn't occur to me to write "sequence".. kept thinking about intervals

Answer (score 111, accepted):

In R the equivalent function is `seq` and you can use it with the option `by`:

```
seq(from = 5, to = 100, by = 5)
# [1]   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60  65  70  75  80  85  90  95 100
```

---

In addition to `by` you can also have other options such as `length.out` and `along.with`.

**length.out**: If you want to get a total of 10 numbers between 0 and 1, for example:

```
seq(0, 1, length.out = 10)
# gives 10 equally spaced numbers from 0 to 1
```

**along.with**: It takes the length of the vector you supply as input and provides a vector from 1:length(input).

```
seq(along.with=c(10,20,30))
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Although, instead of using the `along.with` option, it is recommended to use `seq_along` in this case. From the documentation for `?seq`

> `seq` is generic, and only the default method is described here. Note that it dispatches on the class of the **first** argument irrespective of argument names. This can have unintended consequences if it is called with just one argument intending this to be taken as along.with: it is much better to use `seq_along` in that case.

**seq_along:** Instead of `seq(along.with(.))`

```
seq_along(c(10,20,30))
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the code

```
x = seq(0,100,5) #this means (starting number, ending number, interval)
```

the output will be

```
[1]   0   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50  55  60  65  70  75
[17]  80  85  90  95 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, we want to divide our vector into a number of intervals. 
In this case, you can use a function where (a) is a vector and 
(b) is the number of intervals. (Let's suppose you want 4 intervals)

```
a <- 1:10
b <- 4

FunctionIntervalM <- function(a,b) {
  seq(from=min(a), to = max(a), by = (max(a)-min(a))/b)
}

FunctionIntervalM(a,b)
# 1.00  3.25  5.50  7.75 10.00
```

Therefore you have 4 intervals:

```
1.00 - 3.25 
3.25 - 5.50
5.50 - 7.75
7.75 - 10.00
```

You can also use a cut function

```
  cut(a, 4)

# (0.991,3.25] (0.991,3.25] (0.991,3.25] (3.25,5.5]   (3.25,5.5]   (5.5,7.75]  
# (5.5,7.75]   (7.75,10]    (7.75,10]    (7.75,10]   
#Levels: (0.991,3.25] (3.25,5.5] (5.5,7.75] (7.75,10]
```

Comment: I'd suggest  using `length.out = b + 1` instead of the more complicated `by = (max(a) - min(a)) / b`.

Comment: Indeed. The function is helpful for calculations to find the number of intervals (for example Sturge's rule)